# scala map - what's the best way to try a different key if a key doesn't exist

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Given a Map in Scala, I want to try a first key, if not found, try a different key, if not found again, return None. The following works as expected:

```scala
val scores: Map[String, Int] = Map("Alice" -> 10, "Bob" -> 3)
val singleGet: Option[Int] = scores.get("NotAKey")
println(singleGet) // None
val doubleGet = scores.getOrElse("NotAKey", scores.get("NotAKeyAgain")) // works ok if no type
println(doubleGet) // None
```

But if I put a type for doubleGet, it errors:

```scala
val doubleGet: Option[Int] = scores.getOrElse("NotAKey", scores.get("NotAKeyAgain")) // ERROR
```

"Expression of type Any doesn't conform to expected type Option[Int]"

So what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: `val doubleGet: Option[Int] =  scores.get("NotAKey") orElse scores.get("NotAKeyAgain")`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ah thanks! can you put it as an answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good intuition on what you want to do, which is:
*"test one key, if that does not exists, then check the second one"*.

Also, you are correct on the return type, because you have not provided any default, and there isn't a guarantee of that either key should exists.
But, your problem is that `scores.getOrElse("NotAKey", scores.get("NotAKeyAgain"))` will return **Any**.
Why? Because `getOrElse` returns the **LUB** *(least upper bound)* of both alternatives. In this case default is an `Option[Int]` but the type of a successful retrieval of the first key, is `Int`.

What you really need is a way to compose two **Options**, where the second one is used in the case the first one does not exists. And that is exactly what [`orElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#orElse[B%3E:A](alternative:=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]) does.

You can create some extension methods over a **Map** to make the usage more easy.

```
implicit class MapOps[K, V](private val map: Map[K, V]) extends AnyVal {
  def doubleGet(key1: K, key2: K): Option[V] =
    map.get(key1) orElse map.get(key2)

  def doubleGetOrElse[V1 >: V](key1: K, key2: K)(default: => V1): V1 =
    (map.get(key1) orElse map.get(key2)).getOrElse(default)

  def multiGet(keys: K*): Option[V] =
    keys.iterator.map(key => map.get(key)).foldLeft(Option.empty[V])(_ orElse _)

  def multiGetOrElse[V1 >: V](keys: K*)(default: => V1): V1 =
    keys.iterator.map(key => map.get(key)).foldLeft(Option.empty[V])(_ orElse _).getOrElse(default)
}

val scores: Map[String, Int] = Map("Alice" -> 10, "Bob" -> 3)
scores.doubleGet("A", "B") // res: Option[Int] = None
scores.multiGet("A", "Alice", "B") // res: Option[Int] = Some(10)
```